# Compiler executable file vbc.exe cannot be found

Tags: vb.net

I am facing the following error in my VB.NET web app:

> compiler executable file vbc.exe cannot be found.

I installed .net framework again and even the IDE, but this error remains. Please help.

Answer (score 4):

I've just run into this myself while play with the CodeDom.  If you are manually setting the version you probably have a some code that looks like:

```
    Dim providerOptions = New Collections.Generic.Dictionary(Of String, String)
    providerOptions.Add("CompilerVersion", "v4.0")
    Dim provider As New VBCodeProvider(providerOptions)
```

If you forget the "v" and have "4.0" as the value in your dictionary item, you will get this error.

Answer (score 1):

I'd guess that you're missing a path to it or something like that. Try going to look in the `[Your Windows Dir]\Microsoft.NET\Framework` and go into the sub folders there and see if there isn't a vbc.exe.

Comment: @Asad: Try adding that directory to the Path (see here: http://www.computerhope.com/issues/ch000549.htm) and see if that makes any difference (might need a reboot).

Answer (score 1):

Try installing the .NET Framework v3.5 Feature if you are on Windows Server 2008 R2.
Otherwise, try installing .NET Framework v3.5.

Answer (score 1):

I solved it like this:

1. Go to Control Panel -> Programs and Features
2. Click: Turn Windows features on or off
3. Un-check the box ".NET Framework 4.6 Advanced Services"
4. Check ".NET Framework 3.5 (includes .NET 2.0 and 3.0)"
5. Click: OK

[image]

Reinstall you software if needed..

Answer (score -1):

Just apply windows hotfixes KB 951708  and  KB 953595 to fix your problem.

More details:

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/832597

Comment: Doubtful.  The KB article deals with an run-time error in vbc,exe; the OP can't find vbc.exe to run it.